# Date input field is not displaying properly on Mobile Device in HTML form

Tags: html, css, forms, google-chrome, mobile

I've created a form that has a date input.  The date input would display and act correctly on laptop/desktop Chrome browser but doesn't display properly on the mobile version on my iPhone 13 Pro Max screen.  I am using flexbox and the date field is a flex item inside a flex container.  I think the display issue is because of a default styling for the date input type in mobile Chrome but haven't been able to find a work around.  I also am using Bootstrap 5 elements for CSS

Here is the HTML for the date input:
`<input class="flex-item" type="date" id="date" name="date" aria-label="Date">`

I've tried adding to the CSS:

```
        /* Add this style for date input */
        input[type="date"] {
            min-width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border-color: black;   
            -webkit-appearance: textfield; /* Disable default appearance on Safari/Chrome */
        }

        /* Add this style for date input arrow icon (for some browsers) */
        input[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
        input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
            display: none;
        }
```

and also the following JavaScript:

```
        // Script to add custom placeholder for date input on mobile devices
        var dateInput = document.getElementById('date');

        dateInput.addEventListener('focus', function() {
            dateInput.setAttribute('data-placeholder', dateInput.getAttribute('placeholder'));
            dateInput.removeAttribute('placeholder');
        });

        dateInput.addEventListener('blur', function() {
            var customPlaceholder = dateInput.getAttribute('data-placeholder');
            if (customPlaceholder) {
                dateInput.setAttribute('placeholder', customPlaceholder);
                dateInput.removeAttribute('data-placeholder');
            }
        });
```

I was expecting that this would stretch the input field across the mobile device screen, which it did, but the height is a little off (I think due to pixel size of the font, but not sure) and also to have a placeholder to indicate it was a Date input box like the other inputs, but it just shows as blank. Also, the date picker doesn't work on desktop now, just mobile.

Here's the results:

Desktop: [Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfjAD.png)

Mobile:[Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wS8qx.jpg)

Appreciate any help with this.  Thanks!